# Javascript you may need an additional loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, es6-module-loader

We are working on the following module js(javascript only), which allows to generate random colors.
Link: [Github](https://shorturl.at/aoCP1)

When we try to install the module on an example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-night-90ibs?file=/package.json), we have no problem.

But when we install the module on a local project, we get the following error:

```js
./node_modules/random-colors-palette/randomColors.js 141:39
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (141:39)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     if (!repeat) {
|       delete cc[hueNumber].shades[shadeR[0]];
>       if (Object.entries(cc[hueNumber]?.shades).length === 0) cc.splice(hueNumber, 1);
|     }
|
```

The problem seems to be due to the use of the `?` (The optional concatenation operator) in the line in question.

How can we solve the problem, do I need to add some other files in the project configuration to make sure I don't have these problems?

The module should not only be used for reactjs, but also as a module pure js code.

Can you give us a hand?

Answer (score 0):

You need [`babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining).

It is included in `ES2020` babel preset.

Your `.babelrc` should be

```
{
  "presets": ["es2020"]
}
```

If you don't use a preset add the plugin manually to your babel config

Comment: So I have to do the following steps:
Install: `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`
Then create a `.babelrc` file with:
`{" presets ": [" es2020 "]}`

Comment: I tried to install both `@ babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` and` babel-preset-es2020`, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does your project have an existing build setup? Does it take source files. and create new files?

Comment: Talk about this, found in `package.json` -> `"main": "randomColors.js"`
The project can be found at the following link: https://shorturl.at/aoCP1
I tried to create the `webpack.config.js, babel.config.js` files, following a guide that indicated this problem, but nothing is not working.

Comment: @Paul any solution to this issue?